# Export Product Data & Attributes to PDF

Tags: magento-1.7, product, extensions, product-attribute, pdf

I'm looking for a way to export product data and attributes from the product page via an `export to PDF` button. Are there any reliable extensions around as a solution?

I'm currently looking at the following 2 extensions:

Global PDF: http://www.boostmyshop.com/english/global-pdf.html

Magazento: http://www.magazento.com/english/magento-ext/magazento-extensions/pdf-export

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have suggest simple solution. I think you want the link at product detail page. when some user click on the **Download PDF** Button then it will generate the PDF of that product only.

For that you have to create one Helper Class. Suppose your Namespace will be Test and Module name will be `Generatepdf`.

Step 1: Create the module Configuration file in `\app\etc\modules\Test_Generatepdf.xml` as below.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
   <config>
     <modules>
        <Test_Generatepdf>
          <active>true</active>
          <codePool>local</codePool>
          <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Test_Generatepdf>
     </modules>
   </config>
```

Step 2: Create the Module Configuration file in `\app\code\local\Test\Generatepdf\etc\config.xml` as below.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config>
      <modules>
        <Test_Generatepdf>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Test_Generatepdf>
     </modules>
  <global>
      <helpers>
          <generatepdf>
            <class>Test_Generatepdf_Helper</class>
          </generatepdf>
        </helpers>
  </global>
</config>
```

Step 3: Create the Helper Class with below code in `\app\code\local\Test\Generatepdf\Helper\Data.php`.

```
<?php
class Test_Generatepdf_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{
   public function generatePdfFile($_product){
       $this->_isExport = true;
       $pdf = new Zend_Pdf(); 
       $pdf->pages[] = $pdf->newPage(Zend_Pdf_Page::SIZE_A4); 
       $page=$pdf->pages[0]; // this will get reference to the first page. 
       $style = new Zend_Pdf_Style(); 
       $style->setLineColor(new Zend_Pdf_Color_Rgb(0,0,0)); 
       $font = Zend_Pdf_Font::fontWithName(Zend_Pdf_Font::FONT_TIMES); 
       $style->setFont($font,12); 
       $page->setStyle($style); 
       $page->drawText($_product->getName(),100,($page->getHeight()-100)); 
       // Hear Add your data as per your requrement.
       // Blank page and pdf headers 
       header('Content-type: application/pdf'); 
       header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="downloaded.pdf"'); 

       // Browser watch 
       echo $pdf->render(); 
    }
}
```

Step 4: access this method in product Detail Page. Make Sure you must have to pass the $_product Object.

```
 Mage::helper('generatepdf')->generatePdfFile($_product);
```

Enjoy :)

**Update:**

If you pass the Product ID in parameter and Load the Product Collection on helper you got the all the detail of product Detail with all available attributes. You can modify this function as per your Requirement.

Comment: ok no problem :)

Comment: @KeyulShah : I followed and got" ( ! ) SCREAM: Error suppression ignored for
( ! ) Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Test_Helper_Data' not found in D:\wamp\www\magento\app\Mage.php on line 547"
> Please check once

Comment: I have Update the code

Comment: Yes the change removes the error but I think the pdf, still needs to be modified, not sure if my system is not configured properly, hopefully you have tested it!

Comment: That's y I mention that you have to change the pdf script code as per your requirement

Comment: Nice, this solution works. We just have to add custom data to pdf doc. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

This may need some alteration

`Edit`

> **app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid.php**

, add the following function

```
public function getPdfFile(){
        $this->_isExport = true;
        $this->_prepareGrid();
        $this->getCollection()->getSelect()->limit();
        $this->getCollection()->setPageSize(0);
        $this->getCollection()->load();
        $this->_afterLoadCollection();

        $pdf = new Zend_Pdf();
        $page = new Zend_Pdf_Page(Zend_Pdf_Page::SIZE_A4);
        $font = Zend_Pdf_Font::fontWithName(Zend_Pdf_Font::FONT_TIMES);
        $page->setFont($font, 12);
        $width = $page->getWidth();
        $i=0;
        foreach ($this->_columns as $column) {
            if (!$column->getIsSystem()) {
                $i+=10;
                $header = $column->getExportHeader();                
                $page->drawText($header, $i, $page->getHeight()-20);                
                $width = $font->widthForGlyph($font->glyphNumberForCharacter($header));
                $i+=($width/$font->getUnitsPerEm()*12)*strlen($header)+10;
            }
        }
        $pdf->pages[] = $page;
        return $pdf->render();
    }
```

> app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/ProductController.php

```
public function exportPdfAction(){
        $fileName = 'products.pdf';        
//check grid for product once if it breaks.        
$content = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml_catalog_product_grid')->getPdfFile();
        $this->_prepareDownloadResponse($fileName, $content);
    }
```

> app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Grid.php

```
$this->addExportType('*/*/exportCsv', Mage::helper('catalog/product')->__('CSV'));
$this->addExportType('*/*/exportXml', Mage::helper('catalog/product')->__('Excel XML'));
```

Add the PDF Export

```
        $this->addExportType('*/*/exportCsv', Mage::helper('catalog/product')->__('CSV'));
        $this->addExportType('*/*/exportXml', Mage::helper('catalog/product')->__('Excel XML'));
        $this->addExportType('*/*/exportPdf', Mage::helper('catalog/product')->__('PDF'));
```

Now refresh the admin, you can export products as PDF.

Please let me know if it works.

Comment: They need pdf export functionality in product detail page not in backend grid.

Comment: @TBI Infotech ok. i will try and let you know.

Comment: I got 500 internal server error. Did i miss something or code need to be reviewed.